# SOAP UI Groovy DB connection

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying the following script:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
println 'Some GR8 projects:'
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver')
sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/agilejury-thehl_MC', 'user', 'password', 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' )
def rows = sql.rows( 'select * from pool_person' )
println rows.size()
sql.close()
```

I expected to see stuff in the script log, but I see absolutely nothing. I have run this as a groovy test step and as a setup script.

Is this script running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
log.info rows.size()
```

I assume you already have the driver jar inside `..\soapUI-*.*.*\bin\ext` or in the classpath.